# Add items to laravel's moltin cart

Tags: laravel, cart, moltin

I am trying to integrate laravels moltin cart but anytime I add a new item it replaces the previous item in the cart. Hence i'm not able to add more than one item to the cart.

Below is the route that handles the add to cart request and the associated controller.

Route:

```php
Route::get('/cartadd/{pid}', 'CartController@add_to_cart');
```

Controller:

```php
public function add_to_cart($pid)
{
    $product = Product::find($pid);

    Cart::insert(array(
        'id'       => $pid,
        'name'     => $product->name,
        'price'    => $product->price,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'tax'      => 0,
        'seller'   => $product->business_id
    ));

    $cart = Cart::contents();

    return view('site.cart', array(
        'cart'        => $cart,
        'page_title'  => 'Your shopping cart',
        'description' => '',
        'page'        => 'home'
    ));
}
```

Comment: What are you using as storage for your cart? (session/cache/file)

Comment: I have not gone into that. I think it uses session as stated by the cart's documentation  'storage' => 'session', //session, cache, file

Comment: If i'm not adding to the cart properly could you give me a code that will handle that properly It is giving me headaches

Comment: If you try to die/dump with `dd(Cart::contents(true));` or `dd(Cart::totalItemsafter(true));` after the insert do you see the previous item in the array?

Comment: No it always shows a single array

Comment: Could you give me a code for how to properly add to the cart

Comment: I think i'm missing something. I had the same issue when trying to integrate Crinsane cart

Comment: I updated the storage to cache and it's now working. Is that a good w to work with the cart?

Comment: It doesn't actually matter. I'd prefer `file` anyway, to avoid any issue in case you ever decide to change your session driver.

Comment: But how does it store cart details in cache. That's something i've not done before

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found was to change the storage from `session` to `cache` in the `config/moltincart` file.

This file is created after running `php artisan vendor:publish` in command line.